# ulimit -a every half hour return back with old value

Tags: return, ram, ulimit

problem with ulimit -a every half hour return back with old value

every time i change it to

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 1048576
open files                      (-n) 2000000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) unlimited
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) unlimited
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

return again to default

how to save it forever

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure you add these settings to:

> /etc/security/limits.conf
>
> ```
> * hard nofile 2000000
> * soft nofile 2000000
> ```

Second, check every user's crontab use

> crontab -e

Also don't forget to check

> /etc/crontab

Check every *.sh running using

> ps aux | grep .sh

Maybe these crontab and shell scripts changed ulimit automatically.

Hope this could help :)